# Zookeeper ignores JVMFLAGS?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Hi I setup my zookeeper cluster and it seems to be running fine. But I'm trying to setup the heap size and it doesn't seem to be respected. I created the `java.env` with `export JVMFLAGS="-Xms3000m -Xmx3000m"` file inside `conf/`...

When I `ps -aux | grep java` I can see `-Xmx1000m -Xms3000m -Xmx3000m`. But when I check with `free -m` I only see `200M` used and `3.3G` free.

- I noticed that the default value is set regardless. Does this affects it?
- Shouldn't Xms fill up the used RAM?

Comment: I also get a duplicate `Xmx` using 3.5.5, via `Environment="JVMFLAGS=-Xmx512m -Xms512m"` inside systemd. `ps` shows: `-Xmx1000m -Xms512m -Xmx512m`

Comment: See my comment on second answer. It will show double but JVM will use the last value. But you need to do this pre touch thing. Of I'm not mistaken. For it to allocate the max ram on startup.

Comment: Hi @user432024, i am facing the same issue. Did you manage to find an answer? Thanks

Comment: See my comment on the second answer about  -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch

Answer (score 2):

The file `zkEnv.sh` contains the following line:

```
export SERVER_JVMFLAGS="-Xmx${ZK_SERVER_HEAP}m $SERVER_JVMFLAGS"
```

and the `"-Xmx${ZK_SERVER_HEAP}m"` caused the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

This is what finally worked for me.

In the conf/java.env

export SERVER_JVMFLAGS="-Xms6144m -Xmx6144m -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch"

Answer (score -1):

If you are using /usr/bin/zookeeper-server-start from the confluent-kafka-* package, you might need to set KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS inside your systemd unit file.

```
Environment="KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS=-Xmx1024M -Xms1024M"
```

Comment: It's not it. I figured it out. Even though you use -Xmx JVM/Linux may not allocate all the ram even on init of the application and even if -Xmx means allocate the max. Linux will ensure the app will get the ram but it wont pre allocate it. There's another flag on the JVM I think it's -XxAlwaysPreTouch which will touch all the pages and forces Linux to allocate the full Xmx on init. I remember saying to myself not needing it so didn't use it. Can someone confirm this?